# Google Maps right menu sliding animation

Tags: ios, google-maps, animation

I would like to reproduce the new google-maps right menu sliding animation (used to display traffic , satellite).
Any idea to reproduce this ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following CocoaPod: https://github.com/monospacecollective/MSNavigationPaneViewController

It includes the animation you are looking for, it's called zoom.